# Running a function that prompts from command line

Tags: python, unix, input, prompt

I have a file written in .py that takes 6 inputs.

I am looking to see if there can be a one liner similar to this:

```
python myprog.py(1,2,1,1,2,4)
```

Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: Im confused can you provide more information?

Comment: I have a code that does some numpy work on these numbers. It prompts like this:

    `What is your 1st coordinate:` 
    `What is your 2nd coordinate:`

I would like a way to simply put in the numbers while I call the program from the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass arguments to your python program via the `sys.argv` list. They are passed in as strings, similar to `C`'s `argc,argv` convention.

Shell:

```
$ python myprog.py 1 2 1 1 2 4
```

myprog.py:

```
import sys
print [int(x) for x in sys.argv[1:]]
```

As you can see, we are using all of the members of `sys.argv` **except** the first. The first member, like `argv[0]` in `C`, is the program name.

If you already have some function defined in your python program, you can add this to the bottom of the file:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyFunction([int(x) for x in sys.argv[1:]])
```

As an alternative, if you don't want to modify your python program, and it already reads its inputs from the standard input stream, you can use shell programming:

```
echo 1 2 1 1 2 4 | python myprog.py
```

or, depending upon how your program reads its input:

```
$  python myprog.py << woof
> 1
> 2
> 1
> 1
> 2
> 4
> woof
```

Answer (score 0):

In myprog.py, add the following code:

```
import sys
myparams = [int(i) for i in sys.argv[1:]]
myFunc(*myparams)
```

Now, you should be able to do this from the command line:

```
python myprog.py 1 2 1 1 2 4
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. I don't have any functions defined in my code

Comment: @NilesBernoulli: The function call was simply an example to show that you could do whatever you like with the list of numbers. It doesn't have to be a function call. Further, your question isn't super clear on what you want to do with the numbers once you've read them. Consequently, I couldn't give you an answer more specific to your needs. However, all the code leading up to the function call is still valid

Comment: Sorry to answer so late. But this really did it for me. I really appreciate it! I'd upvote you if I could, but stack says im too newbie.

Comment: @NilesBernoulli: no sweat! consider accepting the answer (by clicking on the check mark) if it worked for you.